# How can i subtract in a SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to subtract in sql but in my case its kinda difficult.

I have following DB

Table1

```
id........artnumber.......price.......flag.......cid
1         12345001        1200        L         9999
2         12345002        2000        L         9999
3         12345003        500         L         7777
4         12345004        1950        L         6666
5         54321001        500         R         9999
6         54321002        1000        R         6666
7         54321003        500         R         9999
```

Table2

```
id........artnumber.......comment
1         54321001        12345001
2         54321002        12345004
3         54321003        12345001
```

what im trying is: 
i want to select all entrys from table1 having **L** flag
on the result of this i want to subtract the prices with **R** flag from the one with **L** flag. but only  on the one who has his artnumber in the comment of table2

Result i want is

```
artnumber.......price.......flag.......cid
12345001        200         L         9999 //her was 2 R flagged items substracted
12345002        2000        L         9999 //her was nothing substracted
12345003        500         L         7777 //her was nothing substracted
12345004        950         L         6666 //her was 1 R flagged item substracted
```

does anybody knows how to set up a sqlstatement for this?

i found some on a other thread but it doesn't really helps me :)

Comment: You need a couple of joins, and you need to better define "in the comment".

Comment: i know that i need joins :) its also difficult to explain what i want :) im trying my best that's why i postet the result i want to have

Comment: Does each artnumber have, at most, one L and one R entry?  Upon looking closer, this is more complicated.  Can artnumber from table2 have duplicates?

Comment: i wonder why someone devotes a question just because he don't unterstands it! like you see, there ARE people who smart enough for complicated questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a little funky, but here goes. I think this will get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.artnumber, a.price - SUM(IFNULL(b.price, 0)) price, a.flag, a.cid
FROM Table1 a 
    LEFT JOIN (Table1 b INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.artnumber = b.artnumber AND b.flag = 'R')
    ON Table2.comment = a.artnumber
WHERE a.flag = 'L'
GROUP BY a.artnumber, a.price, a.flag, a.cid
```

Let me know if you need me to explain any of this, but the joins should be pretty straightforward.

Also, depending on your types, I'm not sure if you'll have to `CAST` that comment field to do the match. There may be some considerations there. I'm also making assumptions about the uniqueness of your records. In other words, I assume that `artnumber` and `flag` together constitute a unique record.

Comment: so this one works almoste fine... ISNULL returns an error (incorrect count in the call to native function ISNULL) but when i take this one out i have the results i want. the only thing whats missing, if ther is non to subtract, the value is NULL and if i use it with ISNULL(b.price) i have -1 on all nun subtracted results :D

Comment: @Dwza Whoops, you're using MySQL. Try `IFNULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is your data for the L prices:

```
select l.artnumber, l.price, l.flag
from table1 l
where l.flag = 'L';
```

This is your data for the R prices:

```
select x.comment as artnumber, sum(r.price)
from table1 r
inner join table2 x on x.artnumber = r.artnumber
where r.flag = 'R';
```

Together:

```
select 
  l_data.artnumber, 
  l_data.price - (case when r_data.sum_price is null then 0 else r_data.sum_price end) as calc_price,
  l_data.flag, 
  l_data.cid
from
(
  select l.artnumber, l.price, l.flag, l.cid
  from table1 l
  where l.flag = 'L'
) l_data
left join
(
  select x.comment as artnumber, sum(r.price)
  from table1 r
  inner join table2 x on x.artnumber = r.artnumber
  where r.flag = 'R'
) r_data on r_data.artnumber = l_data.artnumber;
```

Comment: thanks for this one but im feeling kinda strange when i see this code :) i prefer something shorter maybe :D

Comment: You are just not used to it. It's rather common to select from subselect statements and this can enhance readability immensely once your statements get a lot bigger. Yes, the first subselect is dispensable. If you replace it with a mere FROM clause, the statement becomes much shorter. I just wanted to show how to get from the simple statements to the composed one. You can use this technique when a task seems very complicated. Write small statements and then combine them. The CASE WHEN is kinda long for what it's actually doing here, but other than isnull, ifnull, nvl, etc., it is standard SQL.

Comment: One more remark: When dealing with big tables, some queries tend to be very slow and one must look for ways to optimize them. My statement should be very fast, because aggregation takes place before the join. This can make a huge difference in performance. Just something you might want to keep in mind for a time to come :-)

Comment: thanks for this explanation. of course i can do this all in more than one select by also using subselects. but the task i wanted to reach was createing a select like the answere i selected. (voted up) :)